# Update field in multidimensional list?

Tags: python

How can I update the `'b'` "column" value in a list of dictionaries, for example:

```
list = [{'a': 4098, 'b': 4139, 'c':222, 'd':333}, 
        {'a': 4098, 'b': 4139, 'c':222, 'd':333},
        {'a': 4098, 'b': 4139, 'c':222, 'd':333},
        {'a': 4098, 'b': 4139, 'c':222, 'd':333}
       ]
```

I tried something like this:

```
i = 0
for x in list:
   x.index(i).'b' = 'new value'
   i = i+1
```

Comment: why -1? It's a simple question useful to begginers

Comment: **Don't** name your own list `list`, it shadows the built-in. Also, consider reading [the tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/index.html), this is pretty basic stuff.

Comment: *"why -1? It's a simple question useful to begginers [sic]"* - this site is aimed at *"professional and enthusiast programmers"*, we're not here to regurgitate every basic language tutorial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's simpler than you think.

```
list = [{'a': 4098, 'b': 4139, 'c':222, 'd':333}, 
        {'a': 4098, 'b': 4139, 'c':222, 'd':333},
        {'a': 4098, 'b': 4139, 'c':222, 'd':333},
        {'a': 4098, 'b': 4139, 'c':222, 'd':333}
       ]

for x in list:
    x['b'] = "new value"
```

First, you were going about python iteration wrong, when you do `for x in list`, you don't need to get the element by index, the `x` is the element inside the `list` you're changing.

Then, to access a value in a `dict`, you do so by using the square brackets and passing in the key. 
That way you can retrieve the value, or assign a value to a key, be that key a new key or not.

And as mentioned in comments, naming a variable with the same name as a reserved word, like `list` or `dict` is bad practice in any language, it can cause confusion for the reader or problems hard to debug.